# Command undefined in longtable table when rendering with document

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a table that I am trying to embed in my document. The table renders by itself without any issue, but when rendering with the rest of the document it throws the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command 1 undefined.
```

Not sure what the problem could be. can anyone help with this? MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\centering
\normalsize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.081\linewidth}>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.536\linewidth}>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}m{0.274
\linewidth}}
\toprule
\ No. & Search terms & Number of \par{}results \endfirsthead 
\hline
1 & childh &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly which latex system are you using? On my TeXLive 2020 the example compiles without errors.

Comment: I am using lualatex via R markdown

Comment: What does "rest of the document"  mean here? Could it be possible, that the part that causes the mentioned error message is not the table but somewhere else in your document? Did you get the quoted error messges from the same MWE you added to your question of from your actual document? If the latter is the case, please prepare a MWE that allows others to reproduce the error message you get.

Comment: Not sure how I can create an MWE. But when I look into the the log file  I see the following:   

    Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1589--1590
    
     []
    
    [39] [40
    
    ]
    
    ! LaTeX Error: Command 1 undefined.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking. Which latex distribution and is it up to date? As leandriis mentions, please make sure your MWE tigger the problem you are describing, otherwise the MWE is rather useless.

Comment: Make a copy of your file, comment out part of it, recomple and see if the error persists. Repeat until you get the smallest possible document that still produces the error message. This is the [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that should allow others to reproduce the error you get.

Comment: daleif sorry realised what you're asking now. I have 'pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)' and it is up to date. 

@leandriis That makes sense. I have managed to do this now. Reflected above in my post.

Comment: @MohamedYusuf: interestingly enough, the updated MWE still compiles perfectly fine for me (except some underfull box warnings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you post generates no error however the error you show can be obtained by adding `\expandafter` to your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\expandafter
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}


\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command 1 undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 \renewcommand\arraystretch
                               {1.2}
?
```

Note that you only showed the first line, if you show the full error as here from `!` to `?` then you will get more context on the location of the error.

Comment: This solves it. Thanks David.

Comment: @MohamedYusuf you were lucky that I managed to suggest code that you had just from the error message, unrelated to code you had posted. Please next time if asing about an error make sure that the code you post generates the error!!